# Transferring apps to new iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, applications

I just got an iPhone 6, upgrading from the 5.

My main computer is a Mac Pro Running Snow Leo, and iTunes 11.4. I backed up the iPhone 5 and when I went to sync to the 6, I got a warning that it wants a higher level of iTunes. I went to the other Pro running Yosemite and iTunes 12 is there, so I backed up the 5 to that computer. The apps don't show up to add back to 6, nor does the 5 backup show to copy it over.

How do I get the apps to transfer? (If I need to transfer all of iTunes from the Snow Leo Mac to the Yosemite Mac, and just update iTunes in place, that's ok too. I'd just like a hint at the best method to get this new phone up and running)

Comment: Apps no longer are part of the backup itself, since iTunes 12 - the theory being a) why waste space when they're downloadable & b) they may be different versions for different devices.

Comment: Ok. Will iTune 11 even run under Yosemite? I'd move it over and update it to 12. Would that keep the apps in iTunes? Not quite sure how to approach this. The 5 had 80 apps, some no longer available.

Comment: I've never tried, idk, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since iTunes won't back up the apps, I tried taking the files, e.g. Evernote 7.9.1.ipa, etc, and moving them from the iTunes 11 to iTunes 12.

When at the Yosemite machine running iTunes 12, a double click of the app loaded it to the folder where apps are stored and pulled it into iTunes to sync.

Now, I'll spend a bit of time and look at the old phone to see which apps I use and would like to keep. Just a click to load each one, at least not a search and download off the store.